# joint probabilities chain rule: does the p(a, b, c) equals p(c,b,a)

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, chain-rule

Hi I am studying joint chain prob chain rule. I found that most of mathematical form is as following:

[image: chain rule]

but some is like as following:

[image]

I can understand clear the second form which using the joint and conditional prob to infer it. How about the first one.
I know if there is condition p(x1,x2,x3...,xn ) == p(xn,...x3,x2,x1) can infer to first form.

I don't know where I can found the above definition in the published book?
how about the two form of joint prob chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the conjunctive list in a probability function is commutative.$$\mathsf P(A, B)=\mathsf P(B,A)$$

Comment: thanks, are there some documents about this. if there is a link it is the best.